# Glassfish 3.1 loadbalancing setup

Tags: glassfish, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I am very new to server setup. I have a cluster with 2 instances in GF.

- instance1:28081
- instance2:28082

I am running my GF in Amazon Linux EC2 instance. What are the options to create a load balancer setup that directs traffic to these instances when I try to access my EC2 instance http 80 port?

1) Do I need to have a webserver to direct traffic to these instances?
2) Is there any options in Glass fish which can handle load balancing without a webserver on these instances? I couldn't find load balancing configuration on my admin console.
3) Is there a way to use Amazon Load balancing to distribute traffic to these cluster instances which resides in a single ec2 instance?

If some one can provide step by step instructions/link reference that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I did a nice write up on loadbalancing/failover and proxy options for GlassFish.
have a look: http://blog.eisele.net/2012/01/throwing-light-on-glassfish-webserver.html